# How to proceed to C++ application development

Tags: c++, database, windows, user-interface

i just covered The C++ Language by B. Stroustrup and looking for some application development.
How to start for it. Means GUI, networking databases and other related stuffs.
Should i use individual libraries or use some big ones like .net or something..
please recommend me the books and other resources to begin.
Thanks.

Comment: First of all you should decide what you want more close.

Comment: c++ .net library, never heared of that oO. for GUI elements you could check out `Qt` at www.qt-project.org. it should have all you need.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for this site.  Please read the FAQ and so on.  And just a tip: if you want to make GUIs, don't start by using C++ in 2013.

Answer (score 1):

SO is not the best place to ask such questions (try some resources for newbies), but here are some tips from my experience:

Do not start practising C++ by doing GUI, networking, databases and other enterprise stuff. Try to start with something simple and try to avoid using much frameworks (or try to understand what is happening under the hood).

If you *need to learn* how to make enterprise applications (forms + database), do not do it C++, as there are more suitable languages for this, e.g. Java or C#.

But it you want to master your C++ skills, try to make, for example, a simple game. And try to do as much things as possible manually. C++ is a hard language which offers infinite ways of writing bad code and you need to *understand* how does it work before going deep into frameworks. This will teach you how to (and how not to) design and write C++ code.

If you decide to make a game, I would suggest www.libsdl.org and www.gamedev.net (there are a lot of tutorials and other learning materials).

As for a big framework, have a look at `Qt` (qt-project.org).